# How to get CPU usage & Memory consumed by particular process in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I want to find performance of single process, as example "SqlServer"

Which commands I should write to find out 2 things:

1. RAM utilized by SqlServer
2. CPU utilized by SqlServer

I found lot of solutions listing all processes, but I want to get only 1 i.e. SqlServer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712631/get-cpu-of-a-particular-process-using-powershell/46197064#46197064

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command to get SQL server process information:

```
Get-Process SQLSERVR
```

The command to get information for any process that starts with S:

```
Get-Process S*
```

To get the amount of virtual memory that the SQLServer process is using:

```
Get-Process SQLSERVR | Select-Object VM
```

To get the size of the working set of the process, in kilobytes:

```
Get-Process SQLSERVR | Select-Object WS
```

To get the amount of pageable memory that the process is using, in kilobytes:

```
Get-Process SQLSERVR - Select-Object PM
```

To get the amount of non-pageable memory that the process is using, in kilobytes:

```
Get-Process SQLSERVR - Select-Object NPM
```

To get CPU (The amount of processor time that the process has used on all processors, in seconds):

```
Get-process SQLSERVR | Select-Object CPU
```

To better understand the Get-Process cmdlet, check out the documentation [on technet here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx)

Comment: Thanks mate! but why VM is showing in minus (-). and Does VM means RAM?

Comment: I have gone through that link, but not able to understand that how VM is showing negative values?

Comment: I am unsure, as I do not get negative values. What command are you using?

Comment: Ok, now able to get correct value. Out of VM, WS .... which values is of RAM? which is show in task manager as Memory (Private working Set).

Comment: Last question, If I want to find CPU & RAM of Service instead of Process then. Commands will remain same or what?

Comment: @AK47 just came across this post; the reason the values may be negative is because the value is larger than what INT can hold.  (which I think is 4gb)

Answer (score 3):

About the CPU I got this working the following way:

```
# To get the PID of the process (this will give you the first occurrance if multiple matches)
$proc_pid = (get-process "slack").Id[0]

# To match the CPU usage to for example Process Explorer you need to divide by the number of cores
$cpu_cores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors

# This is to find the exact counter path, as you might have multiple processes with the same name
$proc_path = ((Get-Counter "\Process(*)\ID Process").CounterSamples | ? {$_.RawValue -eq $proc_pid}).Path

# We now get the CPU percentage
$prod_percentage_cpu = [Math]::Round(((Get-Counter ($proc_path -replace "\\id process$","\% Processor Time")).CounterSamples.CookedValue) / $cpu_cores)
```