# Get CPU % of a particular process using powershell

Tags: powershell, process, cpu-usage

I want to get the CPU usage % (not processor time) of a particular process using a powershell command.

Example: (Windows 8 Task Manager)
[image]

I want to get that `2.9%` with a command.

Comment: See [How to get CPU usage & Memory consumed by particular process in powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844682)

Comment: `Get-Process` gives the amount of processor time that the process has used on all processors and I don't believe this is the same as CPU usage %

Comment: My bad. I was only looking at the first answer. Got it. Thanks

Comment: [PowerShell Problem Solver: Process CPU Utilization](https://www.petri.com/powershell-problem-solver-process-cpu-utilization)

Comment: @galahad Were you able to resolve this ? I am also stuck on the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct answer which is support case then you have multiple processs with same name https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844682/483997

```
# To get the PID of the process (this will give you the first occurrance if multiple matches)
$proc_pid = (get-process "slack").Id[0]

# To match the CPU usage to for example Process Explorer you need to divide by the number of cores
$cpu_cores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors

# This is to find the exact counter path, as you might have multiple processes with the same name
$proc_path = ((Get-Counter "\Process(*)\ID Process").CounterSamples | ? {$_.RawValue -eq $proc_pid}).Path

# We now get the CPU percentage
$prod_percentage_cpu = [Math]::Round(((Get-Counter ($proc_path -replace "\\id process$","\% Processor Time")).CounterSamples.CookedValue) / $cpu_cores)
```

Answer (score -1):

Get-Process -Name system | select CPU

Get the cpu time at 2 instance as (cpu2-cpu1)/(t2-t1)*100. You will get CPU value in %.

```
Get-Process -Name system | select CPU # Get the cpu time at 2 instance as (cpu2-cpu1)/(t2-t1)*100. You will get CPU value in %.

$processName = 'OUTLOOK'
$sleep_time = 1 # value in seconds
while (1) {
  $CPU_t1 = Get-Process -Name $processName | Select CPU
  $CPU_t1_sec = $($CPU_t1.CPU)
  #Write-Host "CPU_t1: $($CPU_t1.CPU)"
  $date1 = (Get-Date)
  sleep -Seconds $sleep_time
  $CPU_t2=Get-Process -Name $processName | Select CPU
  #Write-Host "CPU_t2: $($CPU_t2.CPU)"
  $CPU_t2_sec = $($CPU_t2.CPU)
  $date2 = (Get-Date)
  $date_diff = $date2 - $date1
  $diff_time = $date_diff.seconds
  #Write-Host "TimeDiff: $diff_time"
  #compute them to get the percentage
  $CPU_Utilization = ($CPU_t2_sec - $CPU_t1_sec)/$diff_time 
  $CPU_Utilization_per = $CPU_Utilization * 100
  #Sleep $sleep_time
  Clear-Host Write-Host "CPU_Utilization_Per: $CPU_Utilization_per" 
  #Write-Host "====================="
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Get-Process -Name PowerShell | Select CPU
```

Is this what you're looking for?
Or something more monitoring based?

```
param
(
   [String]
   [Parameter(Mandatory)]
   $Title
)

do
{
   $process = Get-Process -Name $Title
   $process
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
} while ($process)
```

Comment: `Get-Process` gives the amount of processor time that the process has used on all processors and I'm not looking for this. I want the CPU usage %.