# Powershell get process statistics in percentage

Tags: windows, powershell, process, powershell-4.0

[image: Windows task manager]

How can I print CPU, memory, disk and network statistics in percentage for a particular process or service using Windows Powershell? I want to print the process statistics shown by task manager using Powershell. I tried using `Get-Process` cmdlet but it does not give values in percentage.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155726/how-to-get-cpu-usage-memory-consumed-by-particular-process-in-powershell-scrip

Comment: This is giving statistics in MB or seconds. I want the the statistics in percentage.

Comment: There's no native cmdlet, what's happening in the background is too complicated for this post. I will find the link explaining what the percentages mean, and how to get it. It's not a simple answer though. You'll most likely have to come up with the logic on how to compare each value against each other

Comment: You can have a look at [this script](https://github.com/santysq/Get-ServerStatus), I haven't touched that code in ages and it is pretty awful. It will give you what you want tho, I think.